# Is NSUInteger equal to [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong]?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to create an app that will use very large numbers. I was wondering if the storage power of [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong] is the max number I can get? And if NSUInteger has the same storage power as a [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `uint64_t` (64-bit unsigned integer, which is the same as `unsigned long long`).

You don't want to use `NSNumber` unless you are storing the vales within an Objective-C collection class (`NSArray`, for example), as they are immutable making them very difficult and expensive to manipulate.

Comment: If I use uint64_t can i still save it to core data or do I have to covert it into a NSNumber?

Comment: @OviSatrob No, I don't believe you can.

Comment: @OviSatrob: You can store uint64_t directly if you choose the option "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" when creating the managed object subclasses in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

NSUInteger is a typedef of a basic c-type.  The exact type depends on your platform:

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 ||        NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

So sizes can vary by implementation of C, but unsigned long is at least 32 bits and unsigned long long is at least 64 bits.

Using types where you know the size is probably better when you're worried about overflowing.  They can always be wrapped in objective-C types if needed.

uint64_t which holds a number up to UINT64_MAX might be useful.

```
#define UINT64_MAX (18446744073709551615ULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the largest unsigned integer type you[*] can store in an `NSNumber` is `unsigned long long` - and on current systems expect this to be 64 bits.

Is this type equivalent to `NSUInteger`? No, that is platform dependent and is either an `int` or `long`, but not a `long long`. Just use `unsigned long long` or `typedef` it, e.g.:

```
typedef unsigned long long MYULongLong
```

You could use a sized type, such as `uint64_t`, but there are no matching sized methods on `NSNumber`. You can address that by adding such methods to `NSNumber` using a category and conditional code based on `sizeof` - with a little care you can write that so the conditionals all disappear during compilation, that is left as an exercise ;-)

HTH